# Slow mysql query with multiple joins and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I don't know why this query runs so slowly with "ORDER BY" (about 15 seconds).
All the fields in ON clause and ORDER BY have indexes.

```
SELECT
    t_prediction.*,
    t_column.*,
    t_user.*,
    t_match.*,
    t_label.*,
    t_competition.*,

    -- COMPETITION_COUNTRY.t_country_id AS t_competition_country_id,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY.t_country_confederation_id AS t_competition_country_confederation_id,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY.t_country_name AS t_competition_country_name,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY.t_country_flag AS t_competition_country_flag,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY.t_country_flag_thumbnail AS t_competition_country_flag_thumbnail,

    -- COMPETITION_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_id AS t_competition_country_confederation_id,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_name AS t_competition_country_confederation_name,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_acronym AS t_competition_country_confederation_acronym,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo AS t_competition_country_confederation_logo,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo_medium AS t_competition_country_confederation_logo_medium,
    COMPETITION_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo_thumbnail AS t_competition_country_confederation_logo_thumbnail,

    HOST_TEAM.t_team_id AS t_host_team_id,
    HOST_TEAM.t_team_logo AS t_host_team_logo,
    HOST_TEAM.t_team_logo_medium AS t_host_team_logo_medium,
    HOST_TEAM.t_team_logo_thumbnail AS t_host_team_logo_thumbnail,
    HOST_TEAM.t_team_name AS t_host_team_name,
    HOST_TEAM.t_team_abbr AS t_host_team_abbr,

    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_id AS t_host_team_country_id,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_confederation_id AS t_host_team_country_confederation_id,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_name AS t_host_team_country_name,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_flag AS t_host_team_country_flag,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_flag_thumbnail AS t_host_team_country_flag_thumbnail,

    -- HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_id AS t_host_team_country_confederation_id,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_name AS t_host_team_country_confederation_name,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_acronym AS t_host_team_country_confederation_acronym,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo AS t_host_team_country_confederation_logo,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo_medium AS t_host_team_country_confederation_logo_medium,
    HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo_thumbnail AS t_host_team_country_confederation_logo_thumbnail,

    GUEST_TEAM.t_team_id AS t_guest_team_id,
    GUEST_TEAM.t_team_logo AS t_guest_team_logo,
    GUEST_TEAM.t_team_logo_medium AS t_guest_team_logo_medium,
    GUEST_TEAM.t_team_logo_thumbnail AS t_guest_team_logo_thumbnail,
    GUEST_TEAM.t_team_name AS t_guest_team_name,
    GUEST_TEAM.t_team_abbr AS t_guest_team_abbr,

    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_id AS t_guest_team_country_id,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_confederation_id AS t_guest_team_country_confederation_id,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_name AS t_guest_team_country_name,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_flag AS t_guest_team_country_flag,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_flag_thumbnail AS t_guest_team_country_flag_thumbnail,

    -- GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_id AS t_guest_team_country_confederation_id,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_name AS t_guest_team_country_confederation_name,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_acronym AS t_guest_team_country_confederation_acronym,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo AS t_guest_team_country_confederation_logo,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo_medium AS t_guest_team_country_confederation_logo_medium,
    GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_logo_thumbnail AS t_guest_team_country_confederation_logo_thumbnail

FROM t_prediction
JOIN t_column ON t_column_id  = t_prediction_column_id
JOIN t_event ON t_event_id  = t_column_event_id
JOIN t_user ON t_user_id = t_column_user_id
JOIN t_match ON t_match_id = t_prediction_match_id
LEFT JOIN t_label ON t_match_label_id = t_label_id
JOIN t_competition ON t_match_competition_id = t_competition_id

JOIN  t_country COMPETITION_COUNTRY
    ON COMPETITION_COUNTRY.t_country_id = t_competition_country_id
LEFT JOIN t_confederation COMPETITION_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION
    ON t_confederation_id = COMPETITION_COUNTRY.t_country_confederation_id

JOIN t_team HOST_TEAM
    ON HOST_TEAM.t_team_id = t_match_host_id
JOIN t_country HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY
    ON HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_id = HOST_TEAM.t_team_country_id
LEFT JOIN t_confederation HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION
    ON HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_id = HOST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_confederation_id

JOIN t_team GUEST_TEAM
    ON GUEST_TEAM.t_team_id = t_match_guest_id
JOIN t_country GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY
    ON GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_id = GUEST_TEAM.t_team_country_id
LEFT JOIN t_confederation GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION
    ON GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY_CONFEDERATION.t_confederation_id = GUEST_TEAM_COUNTRY.t_country_confederation_id

ORDER BY t_prediction_datetime DESC
```

[image: EXPLAIN]

Without ORDER BY the query runs in about 0.005 seconds

Any idea how can i solve this issue?

EDIT: (tables definition)

```
CREATE TABLE `t_column` (
  `t_column_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_column_event_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_column_user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_column_redeem_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_column_code` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_column_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_column_id`),
  KEY `t_column_event_id` (`t_column_event_id`),
  KEY `t_column_user_id` (`t_column_user_id`),
  KEY `t_column_redeem_datetime` (`t_column_redeem_datetime`),
  KEY `t_column_code` (`t_column_code`),
  KEY `t_column_status` (`t_column_status`),
  KEY `t_column_id` (`t_column_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Colonne';



CREATE TABLE `t_competition` (
  `t_competition_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_competition_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_competition_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_competition_country_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_competition_logo` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_competition_logo_medium` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_competition_logo_thumbnail` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_competition_id`),
  KEY `t_competition_id` (`t_competition_id`),
  KEY `t_competition_country_id` (`t_competition_country_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Competizione (campionato, torneo)';

CREATE TABLE `t_confederation` (
  `t_confederation_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_confederation_name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_confederation_acronym` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_confederation_logo` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_confederation_logo_medium` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_confederation_logo_thumbnail` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_confederation_id`),
  KEY `t_confederation_id` (`t_confederation_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Football Confederations (ie UEFA)';

CREATE TABLE `t_country` (
  `t_country_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_country_confederation_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_country_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_country_flag` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_country_flag_thumbnail` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_country_id`),
  KEY `t_country_confederation_id` (`t_country_confederation_id`),
  KEY `t_country_id` (`t_country_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Paesi';

CREATE TABLE `t_event` (
  `t_event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_event_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_event_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_event_start_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `t_event_end_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `t_event_logo` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_event_logo_medium` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_event_logo_thumbnail` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_event_status` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_event_id`),
  KEY `t_event_id` (`t_event_id`),
  KEY `t_event_start_datetime` (`t_event_start_datetime`),
  KEY `t_event_end_datetime` (`t_event_end_datetime`),
  KEY `t_event_status` (`t_event_status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Eventi (totoamici mondiali, totoamici campionato, totoamici 2015)';

CREATE TABLE `t_label` (
  `t_label_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_label_event_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `t_label_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_label_id`),
  KEY `t_label_event_id` (`t_label_event_id`),
  KEY `t_label_id` (`t_label_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `t_match` (
  `t_match_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_match_event_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_match_competition_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_match_host_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_match_guest_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_match_host_score` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_match_guest_score` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_match_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `t_match_status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `t_match_label_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_match_id`),
  KEY `t_match_event_id` (`t_match_event_id`),
  KEY `t_match_competition_id` (`t_match_competition_id`),
  KEY `t_match_host_id` (`t_match_host_id`),
  KEY `t_match_guest_id` (`t_match_guest_id`),
  KEY `t_match_datetime` (`t_match_datetime`),
  KEY `t_match_label_id` (`t_match_label_id`),
  KEY `t_match_status` (`t_match_status`),
  KEY `t_match_id` (`t_match_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Incontri';

CREATE TABLE `t_prediction` (
  `t_prediction_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_prediction_match_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `t_prediction_column_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_prediction_datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `t_prediction_value` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_prediction_id`),
  KEY `t_prediction_id` (`t_prediction_id`),
  KEY `t_prediction_match_id` (`t_prediction_match_id`),
  KEY `t_prediction_column_id` (`t_prediction_column_id`),
  KEY `t_prediction_datetime` (`t_prediction_datetime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='1, X, 2';

CREATE TABLE `t_team` (
  `t_team_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_team_logo` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_team_logo_medium` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_team_logo_thumbnail` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_team_country_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_team_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_team_abbr` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_team_id`),
  KEY `t_team_id` (`t_team_id`),
  KEY `t_team_country_id` (`t_team_country_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Squadre';

CREATE TABLE `t_user` (
  `t_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_user_confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `t_user_first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_user_last_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_user_email` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_user_password` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_user_salt` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_user_team_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `t_user_photo` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_user_photo_medium` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_user_photo_thumbnail` varchar(2083) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_user_confirmation_code` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `t_user_datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `t_user_email_2` (`t_user_email`),
  KEY `t_user_id` (`t_user_id`),
  KEY `t_user_email` (`t_user_email`),
  KEY `t_user_team_id` (`t_user_team_id`),
  KEY `t_user_datetime` (`t_user_datetime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Utenti';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_prediction_full`;
```

Comment: Without the schema and the execution plan (`EXPLAIN` is your friend), nothing we can do.

Comment: what do you need exactly? EXPLAIN of the query and the table structure?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using subqueries is a bad idea.  Start by removing all the subqueries that only refer to one table.

So, instead of:

```
JOIN (
SELECT
    t_team_id AS t_guest_team_id,
    t_team_logo AS t_guest_team_logo,
    t_team_logo_medium AS t_guest_team_logo_medium,
    t_team_logo_thumbnail AS t_guest_team_logo_thumbnail,
    t_team_country_id AS t_guest_team_country_id,
    t_team_name AS t_guest_team_name,
    t_team_abbr AS t_guest_team_abbr
FROM
    t_team
) G
```

Just do:

```
JOIN t_team G
```

Then refer to the columns using `G`.

MySQL actually creates the derived tables when you use a subquery.  This is unnecessary overhead.  Plus MySQL loses the ability to use indexes on the result.

Comment: the reason why i use subqueries is because otherwise i cant refer to fields anymore since their name are duplicated in the results (php PDO fetch_assoc).

Comment: i don't know what your talking about. can you please explain it posting a full anwer? thank you in advance

Comment: @razorxan . . . Your query is already using `as` in the subqueries.  Just use this in the outermost query instead.

Comment: there's no such "outermost" query in my query. You're suggesting to wrap the entire query in a select with all the aliases i need?

Comment: @razorxan Don't use `SELECT *` in the outer query, list all the columns explicitly. Use `SELECT ..., G.team_id AS t_guest_team_id, ...`.

Comment: For tables that you don't need to rename columns, you can abbreviate it to `t_bet.*, t_column.*, ...`

Comment: To optimize a query, **we need to see the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: @AndyLester Edited with the tables structure